# Ken Burns effect with JQuery animate doesn't work with Firefox and Opera

Tags: jquery, firefox

I'm trying do implement a Ken Burns (pan and zoom on a picture) with JQuery but that doesn't work with Firefox (12.0) and Opera :

```
 var endCss = {
     'background-position-x': '-20px',
     'background-position-y': '-200px',
     'background-size': '1100px'
 };
 var frame = $('#myid');
 frame.animate(endCss, 1000);
```

The background-size does change but not it's position.

Does anybody can tell if I'm doing something wrong or if I'm in front off a bug ?

PS : this works fine in Chrome and Safari

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox and Opera don't have support for `background-position-x` or `background-position-y` - these are not spec.

Not sure if this will help as you may want to change both `x` and `y` on each step, but here is a rather informative answer: [Animate background position y in Firefox with Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10449474/animate-background-position-y-in-firefox-with-jquery)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I thought it was handled since "background-position" is.