# jQuery animate change

Tags: jquery

Do anybody see problem here? It's not working.

```
$('#div1').hover(
                function () {                       
                    $('#div2').stop().animate({ backgroundPosition : '(0 -60px)' }, 500);                       
                    $('#div3').stop().animate({ marginRight : '-=10px;' }, 500);
                },
                function () {                   
                    $('#div2').stop().animate({ backgroundPosition : '(0 0)'}, 500);                        
                    $('#div3').stop().animate({ marginRight : '+=10px;'}, 500);
                });
```

Comment: You can't animate the background position, only one value can be animated at a time.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle reproducing the bug?

Comment: i made mistake while typing here, thats not main problem :)

Comment: yep, http://jsfiddle.net/exEqP/

Comment: You need to load jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/exEqP/2/)**

You had semi-colons in margin-right width and parenthesis in the background position.

Also, you didn't load jQuery in the fiddle.

```
$('#div1').hover(
    function () {                       
        $('#div2').stop().animate({ 'background-position-x' : '0px', 'background-position-y': '-60px' }, 500);                        
        $('#div3').stop().animate({ 'margin-right' : '-=10px' }, 500);
     },
    function () {
        $('#div2').stop().animate({ 'background-position-x' : '0px', 'background-position-y': '0px'}, 500);                        
        $('#div3').stop().animate({ 'margin-right' : '+=10px'}, 500);
});
```

I also stringified the css definitions, sometimes they don't work right otherwise, so I use strings always just in case.

Seperated the x and y values as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171080/jquery-animate-background-position).

Comment: changed, but didn't help :(

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
$('#div2').stop().animate({ backgroundPosition : '(0 -60px)' }, 500);
```

is invalid!

jQuery does'nt understand `'(0 -60px)'`, so nothing happens, and you can't animate both values anyway, as animate only accepts one value at a time, if I remember correctly that would be the X axis, not the Y axis. You'll need to use the `step()` method for that:

**EDIT:**

There's actually a solution to the background animation issue in this answer, that's cross-browser :

**[JQuery Animate Background Image on Y-axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12340130/jquery-animate-background-image-on-y-axis)**

Comment: ok, but even if I exclude background position change from code, margin change dont work :(

Comment: That is because you included a semicolon after the value you're trying to animate. Try this `$('#div3').stop().animate({ marginRight: '+=10px' }, 500);`

Comment: @fandrejevic - You're welcome! I also added a solution to the background animation stuff.