# Background image not moving by jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to move the background image of a division by means of jquery animation and it is not moving .The image merely shakes when I try to move it .
I want to create a slideshow and want the background image to move ,lets say on click ,I want the background image to occupy the full division and then on click it should maintain its size and move towards right or left .Please check the code here
http://jsfiddle.net/sSYKD/1/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.8.js"></script>
<style>

.blueScreen {
background:url(http://s21.postimg.org/quy8jsc0n/blue_Screen.png);
background-size:100% 100%;
width:100%;
height:500px;

}
.contentBlueScreen {
display:inline-block;
color:white;
background:url(http://i.imgur.com/a5m0HGp.png);
background-size:100% 100%;
width:100%;
height:500px;
}
</style>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#theButton").click(function() {
$(".contentBlueScreen").animate({backgroundPosition:"200%"},3000);
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="blueScreen">
<div class="contentBlueScreen">
<button id="theButton">MOve it</button>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's great, an image of the problem showing us how it doesn't move, just shakes, will surely help us solve this right away !

Comment: can we see your code please?

Comment: Please check it now .

Answer (score 1):

jQuery does not animate `backgroundPosition`, as it usually takes two values, and jQuery only understands regular numeric values that can be incremented.

There's a solution to animate the background X and Y positions here :
[JQuery Animate Background Image on Y-axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12340130/jquery-animate-background-image-on-y-axis)

Comment: And yes if you modify the background size the animation will also start working .

Comment: Can you please check your solution on jsfiddle and tell me if it is working .Thank you .

Answer (score 0):

You could just move the whole div.

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/sSYKD/5/)**

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#theButton").click(function () {
        $(".contentBlueScreen").animate({
            left: "200%"
        }, 1500).animate({
            left: 0
        }, 1500);
    });
});
```

CSS

```
.blueScreen {
    background:url(http://s21.postimg.org/quy8jsc0n/blue_Screen.png);
    background-size:100% 100%;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.contentBlueScreen {
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    color:white;
    width:400%;
    height:100%;
}
img {
   float:left;
    list-style:none;
    position:relative;
    width:25%;
    height:500px;
    position:relative;

}
```

HTML

```
<div class="blueScreen">
    <button id="theButton">MOve it</button>
    <div class="contentBlueScreen">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/a5m0HGp.png"/>
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/a5m0HGp.png"/>
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/a5m0HGp.png"/>
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/a5m0HGp.png"/>
    </div>
</div>
```