# CSS background-position animate right to left

Tags: css, animation, background-image, background-position

I'm trying to animate a background-image, so that the image appears from right to left.
I have used an image which has a greater width than the div-container, where the background is located. On start, the backgrond is the following

```
background: url(../img/zeppelin.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: right;
```

but when the page is loaded, I want the background to be animated, so that it is positioned left. This should take a eg. 2 seconds and only should be done one time. (the image should be positioned left afterwards).

I don't wanna use any mouse-events or pseudo-classes. Is there a way to animate it by using only CSS? I tried finding a solution with keyframes without success.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12340130/jquery-animate-background-image-on-y-axis

Comment: Just animate "background-Position" properties with CSS3

Comment: add delay to css3 position or create a jQuery event "Load" handler to determine whether the image is loaded before the tranistion.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You could try using `this tutorial`: [**CSS Background Animation**](http://bradsknutson.com/blog/css-background-animation/)

```
@keyframes animatedBackground {
    0% { background-position: 0 0; }
    100% { background-position: -300px 0; }
}
@-moz-keyframes animatedBackground {
    0% { background-position: 0 0; }
    100% { background-position: -300px 0; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes animatedBackground {
    0% { background-position: 0 0; }
    100% { background-position: -300px 0; }
}
@-ms-keyframes animatedBackground {
    0% { background-position: 0 0; }
    100% { background-position: -300px 0; }
}
@-o-keyframes animatedBackground {
    0% { background-position: 0 0; }
    100% { background-position: -300px 0; }
}

html { 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    background-image: url(background.png);
    background-position: 0px 0px;

    animation: animatedBackground 10s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: animatedBackground 10s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation: animatedBackground 10s linear infinite;
    -ms-animation: animatedBackground 10s linear infinite;
    -o-animation: animatedBackground 10s linear infinite;
}
```

**Example here**: http://jsfiddle.net/verber/6rAGT/5/

Hope it that what you need)

Comment: the animation runs forever, so I changed it a litte bit. now it only runs once and does not reset to the position of the beginning:        --> animation: animatedBackground 10s linear forwards ;

Answer (score 1):

working link: http://sagiavinash.com/labs/tests/css_anim/

This is an unorthodox trick.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    .img{
      width:1000px;
      height:500px;
      background:url(1.jpg) no-repeat left;
      transition:background-position 1s;
      -ms-transition:background-position 1s;
      -moz-transition:background-position 1s;
      -o-transition:background-position 1s;
      -webkit-transition:background-position 1s;    
      }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="img"></div>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</body>
</html>
```

style.css:

```
img{
  background-position:right;
```

whats happening here is initially the css mentioned in the `<style>` is rendered.
later since the external stylesheet is in the body just before `</body>`.
So style.css is loaded after the resources in the  are loaded. so there is a lag in implementation of the css which allows us to apply a css transition.

NO JAVASCRIPT, NO EVENTS still we get what we want!

Answer (score 0):

you need to use animation and numbers for value,so it can calculate each position in between start - end.
 basicly it would be :

```
html {
  background:url(http://gravatar.com/avatar/21ffdef6c07de75379e31a0da98d9543?s=512) no-repeat;
  background-size:10%;/* demo purpose */
  background-position: 100% 0;
  animation: bgmve 2s;
}
@keyframes bgmve {
  to {background-position: 0 0;} /* make it short */
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rqwub/)

---

to fire animation on load you can add a class to html via javascript:

```
    onload=function() {
      var root = document.getElementsByTagName( 'html' )[0]; // '0' to assign the first (and only `HTML` tag)

    root.setAttribute( "class", "move" );

}
```

and css turns to be :

```
html {
  background:url(http://gravatar.com/avatar/21ffdef6c07de75379e31a0da98d9543?s=512) no-repeat;
  background-size:10%;
  background-position: 100% 0;
}
.move {
  animation: bgmve 2s;
}
@keyframes bgmve {
  to {background-position: 0 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have tagged Jquery. So will provide you with Jquery function for that.

```
$( "#ID" ).animate({
    left: "50px",
     }, 2000);
```

For class:

```
 $( ".class" ).animate({
        left: "50px",
         }, 2000);
```

You can change your value of "Left" acc. to the position you want to give.

Comment: this will animate the div not background position

Comment: You can encase image in your div. I am doing it currently in my project.

Comment: And it is better to encase it in div for responsiveness across browsers.

Comment: but by this way you are not animating background image position, Actually you are  animating the position of the div.

Comment: Placing naked image in your code is not advised that is why. Encase everything in some tag namely div.

Comment: read the question again buddy, he's not asking you to animate a div. Actually @adeneo has given a very fine example on this.just follow his link to the question in the comments.

Comment: I am just giving my solution. Buddy. Here I modified it for you by using CSS class. And animate also works on image too. So just update yourself rather than arguing.

Answer (score -2):

set `position:relative;` to the image with `left:50%;` for example and on document.ready event reduce the left value to e.g. 0 using jquery animate.

Check out **[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Karim_AG/4U7Fp/)**